# how can I master (the) in a text?

Tags: grammar

Here, I pose the same text in two ways; with (the) and without it by using empty brackets (). I pose the original text first and the non-original text second and I need to know the difference .

1- in many respects, **(the)** American character has been shaped by the moral convictions of **(the)** English puritans. many historians feel that the puritan ethic of thrift contributed to the success of capitalism. founding a new society in north America was a business venture as well as a spiritual one. for **(the)** puritans, **(the)** physical world and **(the)** spiritual world are intertwined. because **(the)** puritans believed that wealth was a sign of **( )** God's favor, they strove to attain it.

2- in many respects, **( )** American character has been shaped by the moral convictions of **( )** English puritans. many historians feel that the puritan ethic of thrift contributed to the success of capitalism. founding a new society in north America was a business venture as well as a spiritual one. for **( )** puritans, **( )** physical world and **( )** spiritual world are intertwined. because **( )** puritans believed that wealth was a sign of **(the)** God's favor, they strove to attain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that all these definite articles are required except for the one before *God,* since for monotheists the word is treated as equivalent to a proper name. The first *the* in the last sentence could be omitted if you mean Puritans in general as distinct from the ones who migrated to America.

Please note that each sentence should begin with a capital letter, as should *Puritan* as the name of a religious movement.

Comment: I want to know how is the second text and if there is a comment plz clarify why

Comment: and why all definite articles are required?

Comment: 'The American character', 'the English Puritans', 'the physical world' and 'the spiritual world' all refer to specific things or groups of people. See [this](https://www.historyextra.com/period/stuart/pilgrim-fathers-facts-history-mayflower-who-why-leave-religion-new-world/) explanation.

Comment: How is the second text ? does it make sense ?

Comment: Since I told you that almost all the definite articles are required, I regarded it as self-evident that your second version is not idiomatic English.